# Why should operator< be defined as non-member?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

I do some test on hash_map, using struct as key. I define struct:

```
struct ST
{

    bool operator<(const ST &rfs)
    {
        return this->sk < rfs.sk;
    }

    int sk;
};
```

and:

```
size_t hash_value(const ST& _Keyval)
{   // hash _Keyval to size_t value one-to-one
    return ((size_t)_Keyval.sk ^ _HASH_SEED);
}
```

then:

```
stdext::hash_map<ST, int> map;
ST st;
map.insert(std::make_pair<ST, int>(st, 3));
```

It gives me a compiler error:binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const ST' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

So I change the operator to non-member:

```
bool operator<(const ST& lfs, const ST& rfs)
{
    return lfs.sk < rfs.sk;
}
```

It's OK.So I want to know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing a `const`:

```
bool operator<(const ST &rfs) const
{
    return this->sk < rfs.sk;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I check the place where error throws out.'bool operator()(const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right) const'. Surely, I miss the const.

Comment: @MIKU_LINK: Yes, this is necessary to be able to call the operator on a `const ST` object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is

error:binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type **'const ST'** (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Your member function `bool operator<(const ST &rfs)` is declared non-const, so that it cannot be invoked against a const ST.

Just change it to `bool operator<(const ST &rfs) const` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Despite of above answers, I recommend you have a look at:

C++ Primer, Fourth Edition, Chapter 14, section 14.1

> Ordinarily we define the arithmetic and relational operators as
>   nonmember functions and we define assignment operators as members: